# IgnoreRoute with webservice - Exclude asmx URLs from routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, routes, asmx

Im adding the filevistacontrol to my asp.net MVC web application.

I have a media.aspx page that is ignored in the routing with

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("media.aspx");
```

This works successfully and serves a standard webforms page.

Upon adding the filevistacontrol, I can't seem to ignore any calls the control makes to it's webservice.

Eg the following ignoreRoute still seems to get picked up by the MvcHandler.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("FileVistaControl/filevista.asmx/GetLanguageFile/");
```

The exception thrown is:

```
'The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it to work using this (a combo of other answers):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{directory}/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Believe me: this will fail if the web service is in the root of the application. My answer explains why it will fail, and how to get it to work.

Answer (score 18):

Short answer:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{*url}", new { url = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" } );
```

Long answer:

If your service can be in any level of a path, **none of these options will work for all possible .asmx services**:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{directory}/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

By default, the parameters in a route pattern will match until they find a slash.

If the parameter starts with a star `*`, like `pathInfo` in those answers, it will match everything, including slashes.

So:

- the first answer will only work for `.asmx` services in the root path, becasuse `{resource}` will not match slashes. (Would work for something like `http://example.com/weather.asmx/forecast`)
- the second one will only work for `.asmx` services which are one level away from the root.`{directory}` will match the first segment of the path, and `{resource}` the name of the service. (Would work for something like `http://example.com/services/weather.asmx/forecast`)

None would work for `http://example.com/services/weather/weather.asmx/forecast`)

The solution is using another overload of the `IgnoreRoute` method which allows to specify constraints. Using this solution you can use a simple pattern which matches all the url, like this: `{*url}`. Then you only have to set a constraint which checks that this url refers to a `.asmx` service. This constraint can be expressed with a regex like this: `.*\.asmx(/.*)?`. This regex matches any string which ends with `.asmx` optionally followed by an slash and any number of characters after it.

So, the final answer is this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{*url}", new { url = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" } );
```

Comment: I know this answer was posted closer to the time that T-Rex stalked the earth than the present day, but It pointed me in the right direction so I've given it an upvote.  This should be the accepted answer, but such is life.  The incredibly sad thing is that I'm looking for this because I'm trying to add MVC into an old WebForms/WebServices app... which was written a few *years* after you posted this, so really should just have been MVC or something in the first place... *sigh*.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you use:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("FileVistaControl/filevista.asmx");
```

If that doesn't work, try using the ASP.NET Routing Debugger to help you:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Now there's something even better than this route debugger: Glimpse, which can be downloaded as a Nuget package, and allows to debug much more than routes in a less intrusive way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*filevista}", new { filevista = @"(.*/)?filevista.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

This is based on a Phil Haack recommendation stated [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, yeah Ive tried both of those. I can seem to get the routing to match for my URL. ive tried adding a route for the given URL and assigning a handler that throws an exception but it doesnt seem to get handled. I think its something to do with it being a physical file.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the source for your route configuration.  I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say to make sure that your IgnoreRoute() calls are all at the top of your routing definition.

The way IgnoreRoute works is to create a route that matches the ignored route URL and constraints, and attaches a `StopRoutingHandler` as the RouteHandler.  The UrlRoutingModule knows that a StopRoutingHandler means it shouldn't route the request.

As we know, the routes are matched in the order of which they are defined.  So, if your `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route appears before your `"FileVistaControl/filevista.asmx/GetLanguageFile/"` route, then it will match the `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` route.

I may be totally off base here, but it's hard to know without seeing your source.  Hope this helps.  And post source code!  You'll get better answers.