# Asp.Net web-api ajax call 404 method not found

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I am using Asp.net mvc4 web-api.

I got an error 404 method not found, i am calling DelteMenu Method using jquery ajax.   I am pssing argument Using data : of Jquery ajax. if i am passing Model parameter it is working fine  but for other parameters like Guid, String throwing exception : 404 method nod found.please let me know if you have any idea why it is throwing 404 error.

```
//api method
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteMenu(Guid MenuId)
        {
            try
            {
                MenuDA.DeleteMenu(objMenuModel.MenuId);

                return this.Request.CreateResponse(
                                HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                new
                                {
                                    Success = true
                                });


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogDA.LogException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }

        }

//Jquery ajax function

function performdeletemenu(MenuId)
{

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this menu?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteMenu/',
            data: "MenuId=" + MenuId,
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.Success == true)
                {
                    GetMenuList();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                //window.location = JsErrorAction;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            headers:
            {
                'RequestVerificationToken': JsTokenHeaderValue
            }

        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` setting does not work when sending a `HTTP DELETE` through jQuery's ajax function. You will have to pass the Guid in the url itself: `url: '/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteMenu?MenuId=' + MenuId`.

What I do find strange is that a 404 is returned, instead of a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Hi Right you are, but previous error is 404 not 400 bad request. Thanks man..:)

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added the jQuery tag to your question in order to correctly reflect the problem (since it is a jQuery one, and not a Web API one).

Comment: Hi, there is 404 error again with 2 parameters now, can you please let me know is it possible to passmultiple parameters with Http delete?http://localhost:3001/api/BannerWebApi/DeleteBanner?BannerId=64aec9c1-8969-4fc1-ade7-6b5c333f0597&BannerImage%20=%20f05b8579-b746-4066-a520-2af89ffb05d5bg-wrapper.jpg ---- given url showing 404 error

Comment: It is possible to pass two parameters to a `HTTP DELETE` method. So something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in RouteConfig.cs as below

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

I tool reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17058251/2318354

It will work definately in case of 404 Error Method not found.