# Correct fix for 404 error? .net 4.5 MVC error loading web service URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

Using VS2012 I get a 404 error after clicking the "Invoke" button of a basic web service page (webservice.asmx).

I googled about and found many references to configurations in web.config and/or IIS having to do with the handling of requests that don't have extensions, including this: [Getting 404 error on MVC web-site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068770/getting-404-error-on-mvc-web-site)

That article indicated that the problem might be the Request Filtering configuration in IIS (my configuration was correct).

Another respondent said to fix the problem by adding this to web.config

```
<system.webserver>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

When I added this, it didn't fix my problem. What did fix it was also removing the following from the system.webserver section:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

My revised web.config section now looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

My web service now serves (and so to do my MVC pages). Is this *the* fix? Or is this a hack/cludge that will bite me later on?

Answer (score 1):

In your RouteConfig.cs file add below line

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

i got solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17058251/2318354

That's working fine