# ASMX service in a ASP.NET WEB API project

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asmx

One of the applications using our Web API site can only consume an ASMX web service.  I recently deployed the Web API project with the web service to the development server and tried testing the web service using the auto generated web page.

I enabled `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` in the `system.web` -> `webService` -> `protocols` web.config section in order to use the auto-generated web page for testing.  When browsing to the method I want to test, the URL is in the following format:

https://mydomain.dev.com/MyApp/MyService.asmx?op=MyMethod

When I click the Invoke button, I get the following message:

> No such host is known

The URL in the response is in the follow format:

https://mydomain.dev.com/MyApp/MyService.asmx/MyMethod

How do I configure to the route to allow me to use the auto-generated ASMX page for testing with `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` protocols enabled?

Comment: Most likely the route is being intercepted and handled by the web api route. Show how you set up the routes so that we can figure out how to add a route that would allow the asmx to be mapped correctly

Comment: It currrently has the `DefaultApi` `MapHttpRoute` in the `Register` method of the `WebApiConfig`

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the ASMX web service automated test harness, I had to create a custom route handler which implements the `IRouteHander` interface to map the HTTP POST to the appropriate web service.  The custom `IRouteHandler` will return the correct `IHttpHandler` for web services.

WebServiceRouteHandler Route Handler

```
public class WebServiceRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private readonly string _virtualPath;
    private readonly WebServiceHandlerFactory _webServiceHandlerFactory = new WebServiceHandlerFactory();

    public WebServiceRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (virtualPath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("virtualPath");

        if (!virtualPath.StartsWith("~/")) throw new ArgumentException("Virtual path must start with ~/", "virtualPath");

         _virtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //Note: can't pass requestContext.HttpContext as the first parameter because that's type HttpContextBase, while GetHandler wants HttpContext.
        return _webServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext.Current, requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, _virtualPath, requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(_virtualPath));
     }
}
```

RegisterRoutes method in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.Add("MyWebServiceRoute", new Route(
            "path/to/service/method",
            new RouteValueDictionary() { { "controller", null }, { "action", null } }, new WebServiceRouteHandler("~/MyWebService.asmx")));
```

My implementation is based on the following blog post: [Creating a route for an .asmx Web Services with ASP.NET Routing](http://www.ookii.org/Blog/creating_a_route_for_a_asmx_web_service_with_aspnet_routing)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you need to enable `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` protocols for web services in your web.config. You can refer to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228319(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  <system.web>
```

**Update**

You must ensure that there is an [httpHandler for asmx files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33(v=vs.100).aspx) and that it is not overrided by the httpHandler for web api. Then ensure the route is not mapped by your webapi router with something like :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675367/ignoreroute-with-webservice-exclude-asmx-urls-from-routing)

Comment: I do have those protocols enabled in my web.config.  The problem is when posting from the auto generated test page, I get the 'No such host is known'